# Image cropping with paperclip 3.3.1 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, paperclip

I have followed the cropping tutorial http://asciicasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images.
Everything worked fine, image uploaded successfully but cropping is not working. When I select certain region to crop and then clicks on crop button then the paperclip crops avatar and then deletes it. This process is repeating in a never ending loop. As a result I forcefully stops my server to halt it.

**My console output:**

```
     Started POST "/users/change_img" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-07 14:59:29 +0530
     Processing by UsersController#change_img as HTML
     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"k5fMemUGLIgbpIjiguRQKL9eiZ=", 
     "user"=>{"crop_x"=>"230", "crop_y"=>"0", "crop_w"=>"249", "crop_h"=>"249"},        
     "commit"=>"Crop"}


[1m[35mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 36 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h619.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h619.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h619.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h619.jpg[0]' -crop 249x249+230+0 -auto-orient -resize "x100" +repage '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h61920121207-23324-xzdzn7'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h61920121207-23324-xzdzn7'
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h619.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h619.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h619.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h619.jpg[0]' -crop 249x249+230+0 -auto-orient -resize "500x500>" '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h61920121207-23324-z3d34f'

Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1y5h61920121207-23324-z3d34f'
[paperclip] deleting /home/saurabh/Workspaces/eclipse/img_cropper_ws/paperclip_cropper /public/system/avatars/36/original/freedomking.jpg
[paperclip] deleting /home/saurabh/Workspaces/eclipse/img_cropper_ws/paperclip_cropper/public/system/avatars/36/small/freedomking.jpg
[paperclip] deleting /home/saurabh/Workspaces/eclipse/img_cropper_ws/paperclip_cropper/public/system/avatars/36/large/freedomking.jpg
  [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "avatar_updated_at" = '2012-12-07 09:29:29.286191', "updated_at" = '2012-12-07 09:29:29.639348' WHERE "users"."id" = 36
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu.jpg[0]' -crop 249x249+230+0 -auto-orient -resize "x100" +repage '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu20121207-23324-1l0osan'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu20121207-23324-1l0osan'
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu.jpg[0]' -crop 249x249+230+0 -auto-orient -resize "500x500>" '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu20121207-23324-1irzeiq'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-1nreivu20121207-23324-1irzeiq'
[paperclip] deleting /home/saurabh/Workspaces/eclipse/img_cropper_ws/paperclip_cropper/public/system/avatars/36/original/freedomking.jpg
[paperclip] deleting /home/saurabh/Workspaces/eclipse/img_cropper_ws/paperclip_cropper/public/system/avatars/36/small/freedomking.jpg
[paperclip] deleting /home/saurabh/Workspaces/eclipse/img_cropper_ws/paperclip_cropper/public/system/avatars/36/large/freedomking.jpg
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "avatar_updated_at" = '2012-12-07 09:29:29.648417', "updated_at" = '2012-12-07 09:29:29.639348' WHERE "users"."id" = 36[0m
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q.jpg[0]' -crop 249x249+230+0  -auto-orient -resize "x100" +repage '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q20121207-23324-1r94x6v'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q20121207-23324-1r94x6v'
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q.jpg[0]' -crop 249x249+230+0 -auto-orient -resize "500x500>" '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q20121207-23324-m0brtm'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/freedomking20121207-23324-f9rq0q20121207-23324-m0brtm'
```

As you see there is a repetition of `Update` query in the console which never ends.

Also note that the `module Paperclip` mentioned in the tutorial is not working so I did some changes to make it work. Although it worked but caused this kind of awkward problem.
When I checks the image after I terminate the server forcefully, I see that images are cropped successfully in the folders. But then are also deleted in a loop and this repeats.

**My crop method**

```
    def change_img  
      @user = current_user
      @user.update_attributes(params[:user])  
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image."  
      render :action => 'crop'  
   end
```

In the above method, the `update attribute` query is causing problems and is updating the image and deleting it in a loop as you see in my console output.

It seems that paperclip processor in a module is causing this. But I don't know why.

OR

Is it something here in `User` model -

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
                    :processors => [:cropper], 
                    :styles  => { :small => "100x100#", :large => "500x500>" }  




  after_update :reprocess_avatar, :if => :cropping? 

  def cropping?  
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?  
  end  

  def avatar_geometry(style = :original)  
    @geometry ||= {}  
    @geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(avatar.path(style))  
  end  


  private  
  def reprocess_avatar  
    avatar.reprocess!  
  end
```

end

Comment: I found the problem. It's in the user model. Actually, after updating the user, the cropping method is being called again and again. But I don't know how to avoid this continuation. If I remove the if condition in `after_update`, the cropping method will be called each time the user gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

call avatar.reprocess! from the controller to avoid the recursion.